# Проблема с переключением активного класса

Tags: javascript

Суть такова:
Есть несколько блоков серого цвета, и есть класс с красным цветом. Я хочу через `setTimeout` заставить его переключать от начала до конца, а затем от конца до начала, и по новой. Реализовать простую версию от нуля до конца, я смог. А с этой проблема, на последний блок класс не вешается, только на предпоследний, испытал много вариантов, ничего не помогло, может разберетесь в чем проблема.

```js
var blockIndex = 0;
var flag = false;

running();

function running() {
  var blocks = document.querySelectorAll('.block');
  if (blockIndex >= 0 && blockIndex <= blocks.length && !flag) {
    blockIndex++;
    addActive(blockIndex, blocks);
    console.log(blockIndex);
    if (blockIndex === blocks.length) {
      flag = true;
      console.log(flag);
    }
  }
  if ((blockIndex === blocks.length || blockIndex <= blocks.length) && flag) {
    blockIndex--;
    console.log(blockIndex);
    addActive(blockIndex, blocks);
    if (blockIndex === 1) {
      flag = false;
      console.log(flag);
    }
  }
  setTimeout(running, 500);
}

function addActive(index, elem) {
  for (var i = 0; i < elem.length; i++) {
    elem[i].classList = elem[i].className.replace(' active', '');
  }
  elem[index - 1].className += (' active');
}
```

```css
.container {
  min-width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.block {
  background-color: #eee;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.active {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: необходимый код должен быть непосредственно в вопросе

Comment: В общем, вам, если не рефакторить код (а его можно чуть порефакторить), то вместо второго `if` нужно написать `else if` .....и никаких костылей в виде `setTimeout(running, 1000);
    return;` не понадобится.... я в ответ дописал для наглядности

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема в том, что когда счётчик доходит до 4, то заходит в блок

```
if (blockIndex === blocks.length) {
```

устанавливая флаг в `true` и код продолжает исполнять следующие инструкции, то есть он тут же заходит в

```
if ((blockIndex === blocks.length || blockIndex <= blocks.length) && flag ) {
```

потому что флаг уже `true` и тут же вычитает индекс блока.

Соответственно тебе нужно в блоке с `if (blockIndex === blocks.length)` поставить передышку (плохой вариант, но рабочий):

```
if (blockIndex === blocks.length) {
    flag = true;
    console.log(flag);
    setTimeout(running, 1000);
    return;
}
```

либо еще сделать так, чтобы последующая инструкция не выполнялась и при этом запускалась функция заново на исполнение через интервал

---

P.S. Это, в принципе, без рефакторинга, лечится через `else if`, т.е.

```
function running() {
    var blocks = document.querySelectorAll('.block');
    if (blockIndex >= 0 && blockIndex <= blocks.length && !flag) {
     // код по наращиванию индекса
    } else if ((blockIndex === blocks.length || blockIndex <= blocks.length) && flag) {
    // код по уменьшению индекса
    }

    setTimeout(running, 500);
}
```